# Facebook Tab Application Metadata

Tags: facebook, metadata, facebook-iframe

I am creating a Facebook iFrame tab application that features weekly interviews and uses a CMS to manage the interview content. I would like to be able to post a link to my newsfeed that points to the application tab and will show a preview with metadata in the newsfeed. Currently, there is no metadata showing up and it is just a blank link. How can I get Facebook to show a preview of the link to the application tab, the same as it would show a preview of a link to any website when posting to my newsfeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doesn't read metadata from your iframed tab, but you can set up a redirect page with custom Open Graph meta tags as described in the Facebook Developers Forum here: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=96146

UPDATE 2012.05.20: **forum.developers.facebook.net** has been replaced by **facebook.stackoverflow.com**. The link I provided no longer works, but there are some helpful related threads on the new forum:

- http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8407013/open-graph-information-for-a-link-to-a-page-tab
- http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-301-redirect-a-page-in-the-open-graph-and-retain-facebook-like-informa
- http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6053657/open-graph-pages-can-i-use-a-stub-forwarding-page

Answer (score 4):

I know this was asked a long time ago but I figured I'll share more details on how I went about solving this issue:

Facebook does not read metadata from iFrame or application tabs.  In other words, when you share a link of a Facebook tab, Facebook will override the meta data values of the iFrame page with the Page’s default ones.  In order to work around this limitation, you can set up a redirect page with custom open graph meta tags.  Here is how:

1. Create a redirect page called redirect.php with meta data information:

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Name of App</title>

   <meta property="og:title" content="" /> 
   <meta property="og:description" content="" /> 
   <meta property="og:image" content="" />
   <meta property="og:url" content="" />


   <!-- This is a page redirect -->
   <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=URL_OF_FACEBOOK_APP">

   </head>
   </html>
   ```
2. Use Facebook URL Linter  to scrape page (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)
   Enter the address of your app’s root URL.
3. Use Google Shortner and enter the address of the redirect.php that you set up.
   http://goo.gl/
4. Now you can share the new Google Shortner link